# Enable selection inside ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, android-selector

The following problem is driving me crazy. I've defined an xml fragment, using this code:

```
<fragment class="host.helperclass.ServiceListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"/>
```

Then I've implemented `ServiceListFragment` class which extends `SherlockListFragment`.

I've overridden the `onActivityCreated` method, with this code:

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
getListView().setDividerHeight(2);
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.list_selector);
```

Where `list_selector.xml` is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
         android:drawable="@drawable/green"/>
   <item android:state_focused="true"
         android:drawable="@drawable/green"/>
   <item android:state_selected="true"
         android:drawable="@drawable/green"/>
</selector>
```

But the green background for an item is added only when I press the button. When I release it the green background is removed. It seems like the `state_selected` is not recognized. 
Is this possible? If so, is there any way for enable the selection of items inside `ListView`?

**NOTE:**

I've also tried to use a selctor with only one item:

```
 <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/green" />
```

And as result I obtaint that, when I press the ListView item the background become green, but when I release it the green background is removed. It seems that my item lost focus when I pull off my finger from item.

**EDIT:**

I have made another attempt.

I've added inside the onListItemClick method this line of code:

```
getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);
```

and in my xml selector I have put only this item:

```
  <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/green" />
```

But strangely this does not work.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. `state_selected` is used when an item is selected using a keyboard/dpad/trackball/etc right?. You want background to be green even when the ListView is not pressed?

Comment: Okay..I understood...Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Defining the xml layout for the row used in the custom adapter, I needed to add this row, to the root element:

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

But, the attribute `activatedBackgroundIndicator` has been introduced since API level 11, so I have put the previous version of my xml in layout folder, and the new one in the layout-v11 folder.

Also the following statement is required, inside the `onListItemClick` method:

```
getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct state for single choice mode is `android:state_activated`.

I noticed you are using the selector for the list.

You should use it as the background of the list row (the one you use in the adapter).

For example:

**row_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_activated="true"
         android:drawable="@drawable/green"/>
</selector>
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/row_background">

    <!-- your views -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But as I said the background is correctly added when the state is pressed

Comment: You answer has been usefull for finding the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Add this item to selector

```
<item android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/green" />
```

and remove

```
<item android:state_selected="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/green"/>
```

Comment: Refer this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/   You may get some idea